# Python regex non-capturing issue?

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to get all quoted (" or ') substrings from a string excluding the quotation marks.
I came up with this:

```
"((?:').*[^'](?:'))|((?:\").*[^\"](?:\"))"
```

For some reason the matching string still contains the quotation marks in it.
Any reason why ?

Sincerely, nikita.utiu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
>>> match = re.search(r"(?<=').*?(?=')", "a 'quoted' string. 'second' quote")
>>> print match.group(0)
quoted
```

Answer (score 0):

Using non-capturing groups doesn’t mean that they are not captured at all. They just don’t create separate capturing groups like normal groups do.

But the structure of the regular expression requires that the quotation marks are part of the match:

```
"('[^']*'|\"[^\"]*\")"
```

Then just remove the surrounding quotation marks when processing the matched parts with `matched_string[1:-1]`.

Comment: well, I'm quite new, but aren't non-capturing groups supposed to be used to exclude their content in the match ?

Comment: No, like gumbo said, they don't create a captured group. Your regex would have to look something like this `"(?:')(.*[^'](?:'))|((?:\").*)[^\"](?:\")"`

Comment: @nikita.utiu: No, they are just used to not to create separate submatches like normal groups do. If you have the string `foobar` and the pattern `foo(bar)?`, there will be two groups: 0, that holds the match of the whole pattern (`foobar`); 1, that holds the match of the first subpattern (`bar`). With `foo(?:bar)?` you will only get `foobar` and no separate match of the subpattern.

Comment: @nikita.utiu: Only [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can be used to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import shlex
...
lexer = shlex.shlex(your_input_string)

quoted = [piece.strip("'\"") for piece in lexer if piece.startswith("'") or piece.startswith('"')]
```

shlex (lexical analysis) takes care of escaped quotes for you. Though note that it does not work with unicode strings.